# Can Robinson's Axiom be used to prove mathematical induction?

Tags: logic, induction

Assuming that the Peano Axioms hold (without the axiom of induction), and assuming one of Robinson's Axioms, namely

> Every natural number is either $0$ or the successor
>   of a natural number.

It can be shown that you cannot use the above axiom to prove mathematical induction, since there's an inherent circularity, but I can't seem to pin down what will go wrong.

Comment: Can you write down your proof of the axiom of induction via Robinson's axiom, please?

Comment: I've edited my question. I know it cannot, but I can't seem to show why it can't be done.

Comment: What can you even do with such an axiomatic system?

Comment: Is that really Robinson's Axiom? It would seem to imply a universe with only two elements.

Comment: I've again edited my question; it should be "one" of Robinson's Axioms instead of "the" Robinson Axiom.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've fixed it.

Comment: @RossMillikan: "the successor of a natural number" has "a" meaning "some".

Comment: How do you define "a natural number"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of polynomials $f(x)$ with integer coefficients which are either $0$ or have positive leading coefficient.  This then satisfies your axioms.  However, it does not satisfy induction.  For instance, if it did, then it would have to satisfy $$\forall a\exists b (a=2b\vee a+1=2b),$$ since you can prove this statement by induction.  But this statement is not true for $a=x$.